# regex parsing address to not include apt or suite at end

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have numerous addresses that I need to match against each other (mother/children) some addresses have apt, suite etc etc at the end of the line-Been trying to find ways to get entire line w/o that last part-

```
with addy as (select '22 W JAMESTOWN ST APT 22' as addy from dual union 
              select '22 W JAMESTOWN ST 22' as addy from dual)
select addy.*,regexp_substr(addy,'(\d*)(\D*)(\s)',1,1,'i') as no_ from addy;
```

Final result should be: 22 W JAMESTOWN ST
This is in oracle- The look ahead function does not seem to work-
'/.+?(?=APT)/' has no effect

The first line works, the 2nd does not. Any input appreciated- TIA
Lawrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `REGEX_SUBSTR`, you can try `REGEX_REPLACE` to remove the extra information from the end of the address.

#### Query

```
WITH
    addy
    AS
        (SELECT '22 W JAMESTOWN ST APT 22' AS addy FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '22 W JAMESTOWN ST 22' AS addy FROM DUAL)
SELECT addy.*, REGEXP_REPLACE (addy, '\s?(APT)?\s?\d+$') AS no_
  FROM addy;
```

#### Result

```
                       ADDY                  NO_
___________________________ ____________________
22 W JAMESTOWN ST 22        22 W JAMESTOWN ST
22 W JAMESTOWN ST APT 22    22 W JAMESTOWN ST
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Quick question-how do I make that case insensitive?

Comment: Just wrap `UPPER` around `addy` in the `REGEXP_REPLACE` like this: `REGEXP_REPLACE (upper(addy), '\s?(APT)?\s?\d+$')`

Comment: For the sake of completeness REGEXP_REPLACE has a case insensitive option, but it requires putting in all the arguments:  `REGEXP_REPLACE (addy, '\s?(APT)?\s?\d+$', NULL, 1, 1, 'i')`